# InfoPath Error: Still getting "Only Positive Integers Allowed"

Tags: infopath

Getting the following InfoPath error: Only Positive Integers Allowed Error:

Followed following suggestion (well, my 2nd dropdown was already like below) and made sure it's like below. But still getting above error. Please suggest.

If you get an error that says Only Positive Integers Allowed, you're trying to save a string into a column that is expecting a number. Most likely the Sub Project drop down's value is set to a string but because the column is a lookup, it needs to be a number instead. To fix this error, right click on the Sub Project dropdown and choose Dropdown list properties. Then underneath Entries, change the Value from d:Title to d:ID. After you republish the form, the form should start saving properly.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by fixing the "Set a field" action rule for the 1st drop down to store ID of the second drop down instead of title. Now it's all fine. 

I am posting the answer in the event someone else running into same issue.

Thanks
MB

Comment: Does this question relate to SharePoint *and* InfoPath? If not you should ask it in a specific Infopath forum, since it will be considered off-topic for our site

Comment: a bit late, but for the record: yes, this is an intersection of SharePoint _and_ InfoPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by fixing the "Set a field" action rule for the 1st drop down to store ID of the second drop down instead of title. Now it's all fine. I am posting the answer in the event someone else running into same issue. Thanks

Comment: Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the lookup column in sharepoint is not set to required. I was unable to solve this issue for awhile, but I finally noticed that removing the "required" setting on the column within sharepoint will prevent the 'only positive integers allowed' from  appearing on your form!

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT - I repeat - Do NOT create the column in List Settings. Create the fields IN INFOPATH, in your Main data source. When creating the new field, choose the plain Choice field type (do NOT choose a lookup-sourced choice field).

Make sure you've set up your external data connections.

After you've created the field, go into the control properties and configure your choices to pull from the external data connections.

This resolved all of my issues with integer errors, choices not being able to cascade, validation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified the field to not be required, but still need the required validation, you will need to create a field validation rule in InfoPath.

Validation rule:

- Condition: [**field name**] is blank
- ScreenTip: Cannot be blank

[image: Required validation rule]

See the two posts:

- [MSDN forum post infopath-only-integers-allowed-validation-tooltip](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6336a681-d57a-4ca6-b075-4e9a98dfb79c/infopath-only-integers-allowed-validation-tooltip)
- [Blog post sharepoint-2010-infopath-lookup-column-throws-only-positive-integers-allowed](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2012/07/sharepoint-2010-infopath-lookup-column-throws-only-positive-integers-allowed/)

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the field in the list - in the browser. After you customize the form, clicking on "Custom form (InfoPath icon on ribon)". Pull the field to the model, if not automatically, in my case, then it worked.